# Spring Data IGNORE optional parameter in query method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to write some query methods in repository layer. This method must  ignore null parameters. For example:

```
List<Foo> findByBarAndGoo(Bar barParam, @optional Goo gooParam);
```

This method must be return Foo by this condition:

```
bar == barParam && goo == gooParam;
```

if gooParam not null. if gooParam was null then condition change to:

```
bar == barParam;
```

Is there any solution? Can someone help me?

Comment: This refers to an open issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209